# Id chegando nulo na action da controller Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

tenho uma lista de solicitações(Vr), nessa lista criei um botão para finalizar essa solicitação(Abrir Mv).[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clico nesse botão, sou redirecionado para minha view de Baixa, que tem seus próprios atributos, e mais o Id da solicitação(Vr).
Essa parte está funcionando tudo certo, estou conseguindo clicar no botão, e carregar o objeto selecionado na view da baixa. O problema é no [httpPost], Quando eu clico em enviar, o Id da solicitação vem nulo, e o Id da baixa vem com o Id da solicitação.

Action get

```
public ActionResult MvVr(int id)
{
     Vr vrs = new Vr();
     vrs = vrs.BuscarPorIdDaVr(id);
     Mv mv = new Mv();
     mv.Vrs = vrs;
     return View(mv);
}
```

view da Action Apenas A parte que carrega os dados da solicitação

@model SistemaGaragem.Models.Mv

Painel De Cadastro

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">

                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Vrs.VrId, "VrId")

                <fieldset class="well">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelForModel("Motorista", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })

                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vrs.Motorista.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelForModel("Usuário", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })

                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vrs.Usuario.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelForModel("Itinerario", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })

                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vrs.Itinerario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelForModel("VrId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })

                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vrs.VrId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Action HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MvVr(Mv objMv, int VrId)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
         var login = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Id").Value;
         var usuario = db.UsuariosDb.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.ToString() == login);
          objMv.IdUsuario = usuario.Id; // Usuário que Finalizou a Vr


          //objMv.VrId = VrId;
          db.MvDb.Add(objMv);
          db.SaveChanges();
          TempData["Sucesso"] = "Baixa Realizada Com Sucesso.";
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Painel");
      }
      TempData["Errado"] = "Favor Preencher os Campos Corretamente.";
      return View(objMv);
}
```

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Vrs.VrId, "VrId")` está gerando um html, abra essa página no navegador clique com o botão direito do mouse exibir código fonte e verifique como foi gerado o name de input hidden e cole aqui.

Comment: <input length="4" data-val="true" data-val-number="O campo VrId deve ser um número." data-val-required="O campo VrId é obrigatório." id="Vrs_VrId" name="Vrs.VrId" value="11" type="hidden">

Comment: o Nome é `Vrs.VrId` e não `VrId` no `controller`  entendeu o problema?

Comment: Coloque uma linha assim `@Html.Hidden("VrId", model.Vrs.VrId)` vai funcionar

Comment: @Html.Hidden("VrId", model.Vrs.VrId) Desse jeito da erro de compilação.

Comment: <input data-val="true" data-val-number="O campo VrId deve ser um número." data-val-required="O campo VrId é obrigatório." id="VrId" name="VrId" value="0" type="hidden">
E assim o valor em "0"

Comment: @Html.Hidden("VrId", model.Vrs.VrId) - Desculpa, eu que fui burro, desse jeito funcionou, eu que tava colocando "HiddenFor".

Só que o Id da MV(Baixa) tbm está vindo com o valor do Id da Vr(Solicitação)

Comment: é complicado dizer sem ter como debugar mas, se está trocado o campo do valor é só você verifcar qual é o valor que tem que colocar lá dentro...